# python, linux: how to open entire hard drive as one raw binary file

Tags: python, linux

my file is corrupted. I saved the file on window 7 system and the previous working file was overwritten. So I want to recover it somehow. I created a simple python script to search for binary sequence of bytes. I know the exact size of file and header content. I am not very familiar with linux, but I think that everything can be handled as file. So my problem is that when I use standard code:

```
with open(file_to_search_in) as data_file:
      data = mmap.mmap(data_file.fileno(), 0, prot=mmap.PROT_READ, flags=mmap.MAP_PRIVATE)
      ...
```

and use for `file_to_search_in = /media/root/E6EB-10AA` I got error message on linux system

> IOError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: '/media/root/E6EB-10AA/'

Comment: Access the device directly instead of the mount point; you can see the device file descriptor by calling `df` in a terminal window.

Comment: @MatsLindh I used `df` command and it show me  /dev/sdb. So I tried to use it like `python my_script /dev/sdb` but now I got `mmap.error: [Errno 22] Invalid argument` Now it seems to be a problem of one of the mmap argument. I deleted that line and use simple `data_file.read()` Now it seem to work. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe somthing like this: "open('/dev/sda', 'r')"

Comment: should we also include `'b'` for binary mode as `'rb'` https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#open